# Singlespace doesn't use the defined fontsize

Tags: pdftex, fontsize, setspace

As the title says, singlespace doesn't use the defined fontsize.

Is there anything I can do to make it work.

see the mwe:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}                            % vertical space between paragraphs
\usepackage{xcolor}                             % foreground (text, rules, etc.) and background colour management
\usepackage{soul}                               % hyphenatable letterspacing, underlining, overstriking, highlighting
\usepackage{geometry}                           % customize page layout
\usepackage{enumitem}                           % enumerate, itemize and description lists
\usepackage{hyperref}                           % hypertext links
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                           % headers and footers
\usepackage{graphicx}                           % support for graphics
\usepackage{tabularx}                           % tables with adjustable width columns
\usepackage{scalerel}                           % vertically scaling and stretching objects
\usepackage{amssymb}                            % symbols found in the AMS symbol font msam and msbm
\usepackage{multicol}                           % define a multicols environment which typesets text in multiple columns
\usepackage{qrcode}                             % printing of qr codes
\usepackage{scrextend}                          % required to left indent address block
\usepackage{marvosym}                           % includes euro symbol
\usepackage{colortbl}                           % background color for row, columns or individual cells in a table
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}                  % absolute positioning of text on the page
\usepackage{tikz}                               % package for creating graphics
\usepackage{setspace}                           % set spacing between lines
\usepackage{wallpaper}                          % use pdf as background image (letterhead)
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}                       % use dutch hyphenation conventions
%\usepackage[default,scale=0.90]{opensans}      % Use font opensans (supported by pdflatex)
\usepackage{paratype}                           % Use font Paratype (identical to Calibri)
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}       % select sans serif font
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}                 % various title styles
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}                    % coloured and framed text boxes
\usepackage{tabto}                              % moves the typesetting position
\usepackage{pdfpages}                           % Include PDF as annex
\usepackage{etoolbox}                           % Check if an argument is optional in a newcommand
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     % Use accented letters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                        % Use accented letters
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{dashrule}                           % dashed and dotted lines

\newcommand{\signer}[2]{
    \ifthenelse{\not{\equal{#2}{}}} {
        \begin{minipage}[t][4.5cm]{8.5cm}
            \includegraphics[width=5.008cm, height=2.432cm]{#1} \newline
        \begin{singlespace}
                #2
        \end{singlespace}
        \end{minipage}
    }
    {}
}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=30mm,
    right=25mm,
    top=4.5cm,
    bottom=4.5cm
}

\linespread{0.8}                                % change the line spacing for entire document

\newcommand{\signerI}{Ben Maes \\ test}
\newcommand{\signerISignature}{{SIGNATURE}.png}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{9}{10}
\selectfont

testtesttesttest \\
\signer{\signerISignature}{\signerI} \\
testtesttesttest \\
\signer{\signerISignature}{\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont\signerI} \\
testtesttest
\end{document}
```

This generates:
[image: result]

The bottom part is how I want to have it, but I do not want to give my fontsize with it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do a better job trimming your example code to a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Your preamble right now contains lots of packages that has no bearing on your question, and your code requires a signature PNG file that we don't have access to, and so for us to even help you debug we have to do a lot of work just cleaning up your code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you really should do a better job trimming your example code. Your problem already shows up in the following (ignore for now the parts that are between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}                           % set spacing between lines
\linespread{0.8}                                % change the line spacing for entire document

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
  \f@size
\makeatother

\fontsize{9}{10}
\selectfont

\makeatletter
  \f@size
\makeatother

TEST
\begin{singlespace}
  \makeatletter
    \f@size
  \makeatother

  TEST
\end{singlespace}
TEST

\end{document}
```

The call to `\f@size` shows the current font size, and you see that initially you are using a 10 point font. After you called the `\fontsize` command it is correctly set to a 9 point font as you wished. But when you call the `singlespace` environment it is now set back to 10 point.

The reason is that the way `singlespace` works in the `setspace` package calls `\@currsize` after setting the line-spacing, to make sure we get to the correct (relative) current font size at the time. Your document class is by default setting `\normalsize` to 10 pts, and you didn't make any change to the current relative font size, so the when `singlespace` calls `\@currsize` it sets the size to `\normalsize` which is 10 pts.

A few way to workaround this:

1. If you just need to temporarily change the font size, and are happy with the `\baselineskip` being 11pts instead of 10pts, you can just call `\small` instead of `\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont`. This way when `singlespace` calls `\@currsize` it will get `\small` instead of `\normalsize`.
2. If you want to have an entire document based around a 9 point font, you can look into using the [extsize](https://ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) document classes.
3. If you are already willing and wishing to micromanage the interline spacing manually, you might as well not bother with using the `setspace` package and just call `\fontsize{}{}` yourself and adjust the second argument to adjust the amount of interline spacing.